# R Software Issue with log likelihood optimization of a transformation-function with 3 parameters

Tags: r, optimization, transformation

I have a big deal with an optimization problem.
I have got a time series of a stock and a transformation function:

```
     K_z  <- function(z, theta, beta_z, n) {
     z*((1+((z^2+0.5)^beta_z-0.5^ beta_z)/n)^(n*theta))
    }

     K_fd_z  <- function(z, theta, beta_z, n) {
    (   (1+(  (z^2+0.5)^beta_z - 0.5^beta_z)/n)^n   )^(theta-1) *  (    (                           (1+(  (z^2+0.5)^beta_z - 0.5^beta_z)/n)^n   ) + theta * z * (2*beta_z * z * (1 + ( (z^2+0.5)^beta_z - 0.5^beta_z)/n)^(n-1) * ( z^2+0.5)^(beta_z-1) ) )
    }
```

where: y is the stock

```
    y <- get.hist.quote("ALV", quote="Adj", start="2000-01-01",end="2014-12-31", retclass="zoo")
     y <- na.locf(y)
     y <- diff(log(y))
     y <- exp(y)-1
```

theta, beta_z, n are parameters and z is

```
     z <- rnorm(length(y), mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Now I need this inverse function:

```
     K_inv <- function(y)
    {
     uniroot(function(z) K_z(z, theta, beta_z, n)-y , lower=9,upper=11)$root
    }
     K_inverse <- Vectorize(K_inv, "y")
```

the uniroot should be:

```
     K_m1 <- K_inverse(y)
```

and this function should be analyzed:

```
      f_Y <- function(z, theta, n, beta_z)
     {
        K_m1 <- K_inverse(y)
        (dnorm(K_m1))/( K_fd_z(K_m1))
     }
       #            curve(f_Y(x,theta=0.2,n=5,beta_z=0.5),-10,10)
      #Error in uniroot(function(z) K_z(z, theta, beta_z, n) - y,lower = 9,  : 
      #f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Parameter optimization and boundaries could be something like:

```
       p3 <- optim(c(-0.2, mean(y)-0.2, 0.01, 1, 0.4), loglike, NULL, method = "L-BFGS-B",lower = c(-0.2, mean(y)-0.2, 0.01, 1, 0.4), upper = c(0.2, mean(y)+0.2, 0.5, 250, 1.8)
       oi3<-solve(p3$hessian)
```

It doesn't work...I am quite new in R and don't understand my errors,maybe somebody is able to help me?!?

Thank You in advance...

Comment: This needs a flag for R I think, I don't think people who don't speak this language/dialect will be able to help.

Comment: You're right, thank You :-)